# Send/receive SMS in Latvia

Tags: sms, twilio

Could anyone tell which countries would be able to send and receive *SMS* AND *calls* to `Latvia`?

I can't seem to find an answer, it appears that LV numbers can't send SMS, yet I see prices on the pricing page. I'm quite confused as of which country I should get a number in (and the price).

If I get a LV number, does it mean i can send, but not receive SMS? It would be fine for my app (already built, waiting to go live).

Basically, it is a browser app acting as a soft phone (single user), so no landline involved. Is there a way to solve the country problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Looks like we currently only have Voice enabled Latvian numbers (numbers with a +371 prefix).  Buying one costs you $1 US and use can use it to have Twilio make a voice phone call from it or receive phone calls to it.

For SMS, Twilio does support sending international SMS from US numbers, so you certainly could buy a US number and use it to send text messages to a Latvian number.  The pricing for that is [here](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/lv) (scroll down to see per-carrier pricing details).

Hope that helps clarify.